# undefined function put_req_header/3

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have the following module in Phoenix app. This code is basically shared spec example. It looks like this:

```
defmodule TattooBackend.CurrentPasswordRequiredTest do
  @moduledoc """
  This module defines tests that are testing api current password requirement.
  """
  import Phoenix.ConnTest

  alias TattooBackend.Web.Router

  defmacro test_current_password_required_for(method, path_name, action) do
    quote do
      test "without current password", %{conn: conn} do
        method    = unquote(method)
        path_name = unquote(path_name)
        action    = unquote(action)
        account = insert(:account)

        assert make_unauthenticated_request(conn, @endpoint, method, path_name, action, account) == %{
          "error" => "Błędne hasło."
        }
      end
    end
  end

  def make_unauthenticated_request(conn, endpoint, method, path_name, action, account) do
    path = apply(Router.Helpers, path_name, [conn, action])

    conn
    |> put_req_header("authorization", "#{token(account)}")
    |> dispatch(endpoint, method, path, nil)
    |> json_response(422)
  end
end
```

When I run my specs it returns error:

```
** (CompileError) test/support/shared_tests/current_password_required.ex:28: undefined function put_req_header/3
```

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The function is actually `Plug.Conn.put_req_header/3` - you need to either use the full name or import the `Plug.Conn` module.

Comment: and if that's the only function you need 
`import Plug.Conn, only: [put_req_header: 3]`